# search posts by POST ID

Tags: search

This function is no longer working and when I put the post ID in the default search box I get no results, why?

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'posts_where');
function posts_where($where)
    {

        $s = $_GET['s'];

        if(!empty($s))
        {
          if(is_numeric($s))
          {
             global $wpdb;

            $where = str_replace('(' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE', '(' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID = ' . $s . ') OR (' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE', $where);
          }
          elseif(preg_match("/^(\d+)(,\s*\d+)*\$/", $s)) // string of post IDs
          {
            global $wpdb;

            $where = str_replace('(' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE', '(' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID in (' . $s . ')) OR (' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE', $where);
          }
        }


      return $where;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are using might not be working because WordPress's search functionality has been updated, and it's recommended to use WordPress's `WP_Query` class to modify the main query. Here's a better and safer way to search by post ID using `pre_get_posts` hook:

```
function search_by_post_id($query) {
    if($query->is_search) {
        if(is_numeric($query->query_vars['s'])) {
            $query->set('post_type', 'any');
            $query->set('post__in', array((int)$query->query_vars['s']));
            $query->set('s', '');
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'search_by_post_id');
```

When a search is performed, the function checks if the search term is numeric. If it is, it interprets the term as a post ID and modifies the query to fetch a post with that ID. It sets the post type to '**any**' to make sure it can find any type of post, not just regular 'posts'. This should work for any numerical ID entered into the search bar.

Comment: Thank you, it works :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! @AndreaSacconi